# How to validate the password django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a rest application to communicate with my android application but it is stopping me the validation of the password.

I use the User model by default of django and I would like to try to make the server validate the password

I found some other interesting answers but the truth is that django is not my strong point (my specialty is android) and they do not explain well how to implement them in my view

restapp/views.py

```
class postRegister(APIView):

    def post(self,request):
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        cencripM=CriptoMovil(KEY_ENC_M)
        data['username'] = cencripM.decrypt(data['username'])
        data['email'] = cencripM.decrypt(data['email'])
        data['password'] = cencripM.decrypt(data['password'])
        serializer = RegistSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"message":"save","state":"1"})
        return Response({"message":serializer.errors,"state":"2"})
```

maybe it helps some of the articles that I found but I did not understand how to implement them in the view (I repeat my specialty is android)

[many options but I did not know how to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414804/integrate-django-password-validators-with-django-rest-framework-validate-passwor?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[interesting but I did not understand how to implement the view](https://gist.github.com/leafsummer/f4d67b58a4cc77174c31935d7e299c9e)

Comment: If you are not expert in Django,you can try Flask.It is much more easier to learn.

Comment: @NimishBansal No friend is a team project and good for all the normal things of crud I already did, I would only miss this

Comment: The code posted, is that your attempt or something you found?

Comment: @JohanL no friend that's the way I typically treat the data received from android, but if I made several attempts that the closest one gave me the error response of the pass but only in the error log xD and I could never return that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As beginning you don't need to write your customer serializer for validation instead you can follow token base authentication to validate in android as below:

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken

urlpatterns +=[
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', ObtainAuthToken.as_view(), name='get_auth_token')
]
```

Now you can post username and password at `/api-token-auth/` and if it is valid you will get a token in response and response status will be `200 OK`

if you need to customise response then you need to override post method of 
`ObtainAuthToken` as below:

```
class CustomAuthentication(ObtainAuthToken): 
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'request': request})  # this will use DRF's AuthTokenSerializer and pass your request to it
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)  # validate serializer
    user = serializer.validated_data['user']  # you will get user instance if it is valid
    token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)  # gives you token for user
    response_data = {'token': token.key}  #  create dict with token key
    # you can add any other JSON serializable details you want to add in this dict like username or related role/email
    return Response(response_data)
```

Now in `urls.py` instead of using `ObtainAuthToken.as_view()` you need to use 
`CustomAuthentication.as_view()` and

For other setup detail read [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) thread