# Django not REST - API user registration

Tags: python, django, api, registration

I have my first project as junior in my work. It is old (Django 1.8) and it is normal django framework... not REST.

It supports web, and mobile.

I have to create endpoint for mobile to create user.

I think it is not a problem (to create) but I want to make sure it will be save.

First of all I thought that I will create normal ModelForm (RegisterAPIForm based on model=User with full validation (I mean init all fields that are in "backend" not visible for user | cleaned_data for all fields | special overwriten method save() that in addition hashes password, and send email) and in Views I'll add something like this:

```
class RegistrationAPITestView(View):
   def post(self, request):
       form = RegistrationAPIForm(
           request.POST
       )
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return JsonResponse({})
       else:
           #check errors and send error code back
```

Or I should do it other way, by using User object?

```
class RegistrationAPITestView(View):
       def post(self, request):
           #check if user does not exist
           #password1 and password2 validation
           user = User.objects.create()
           user.name = request.POST['username']
           user.set_password(request.POST['password'])
           #init all fields that user can't choose like groups etc
           user.save()
```

What do you think? Do I need ModelForm that I won't even render? It seems to be safer, but maybe I should check it other way? with User object?

Btw. Registration form already exists for web but there is a lot of "web" stuff that I don't need and I don't have to check and there is another method of saving password, so I believe I should create new one.

My code will be revieved in 2 weeks (senior vacations) but now I'm alone and want to do my best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the second option, but here is the problem that you as a junior should avoid. This line will make the server return a 500 error `request.POST['username']` because python will throw a key error if the user doesn't provide the username, to fix just change to `request.POST.get('username', 'value if doesn\'t exit')` also make sure that everything is ready before create the user or you will have records in the database that wont be useful. Call [validators to the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414804/integrate-django-password-validators-with-django-rest-framework-validate-passwor) too and try to cover all possible scenario. Remember never trust the user

Comment: Thank you for answer! I've just updated my code with .get() ;) I'm not using Django REST framework. It's written in Django 1.8, and I have to create normal View but returns JsonResponse.
What in this case? it is still better to use second idea?

Comment: and the other question! How should i return errors like "email is already in use". I should return for instance 401, for wrong password 402? etc.? Or i should return response 200 with a code number like [1] for this, [2] for that?

Thanks for help! I appreciate it very much!

Comment: yes it would be easier to use the second option. You could use the 400 http status to return that something went wrong