# Django AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS for password not working in BaseManager class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-serializer, customvalidator

I want to validate the password with a min length of 9 and I specified it in AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS as:

```
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'min_length': 9,
    }
},
```

I use Django serializer to serializer the request:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    date_joined = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    user_type = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(max_length = 20))

    class Meta(object):
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'mobile_num', 'date_joined', 'password','user_type', 'otp_verified')
        id = serializers.CharField(max_length=10)
        email = serializers.EmailField()
        password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'})
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

Here I want to check for password validation in BaseManager and coded accordingly:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
                user.set_password(password)
                user.save(using=self._db)
                return user
        except:
            raise

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        if(len(password) < 9):
            raise ValidationError("length too short")
        else:
            return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        return self._create_user(email, password=password, **extra_fields)

    def get_default_password_validators(self, password):
        return get_password_validators(settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS)

now = datetime.datetime.now()

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    user_type = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length = 20))
    mobile_num = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    otp_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserManager()
```

In create_user() I tried to check for minimum length of password and validate it accordingly, also tried using class MinimumLengthValidator, but validation doesn't happen. So used custom validation.

Can anyone help me with this code, with the default built-in password validators?

Answer (score 0):

When you create user serialization like this, DRF will try to take exactly what it got from view and put it into the database. You should use `import django.contrib.auth.password_validation` and execute it in `validate()` method. Compare with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414804/integrate-django-password-validators-with-django-rest-framework-validate-passwor).

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, in serializer class add the following:

## password validation

```
def validate_password(self, password):
    
    if not re.findall('\d', password):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("The password must contain at least 1 digit, 0-9.")
    if not re.findall('[A-Z]', password):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("The password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, A-Z.")
    if not re.findall('[a-z]', password):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("The password must contain at least 1 lowercase letter, a-z.")
    if not re.findall('@#', password):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("The password must contain at least 1 symbol: " + "@ or #")
    return password}
```

Instead  of going for BaseManager class I tried the code in the serializers itself and it worked well for me.