# how to get access to post data incoming inside a Django middleware?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am writing a middleware due to which i need to access post data but none of the answers are solving my doubt, i am reading the data like this  but this is working in postman but giving error in  browser

```
  dict_str = request.body.decode("UTF-8")
```

any help is highly appreciated

**error**

```
RawPostDataException at /accounts/api/v1/register/
You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: i need to use request.body when a new user register to check if his/her password  is strong enough, doing it in middleware to improve efficiency , is there any way to get access to request.body and why django gives error on accessing it, does it cause any issue in the application

Comment: Typically you'd do that in the validator of the serializer. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414804/integrate-django-password-validators-with-django-rest-framework-validate-passwor

Answer (score 0):

You can get by `reqeust.data`, once POST body parsed on DRF, accessing to body is hindered.

Comment: I have tried that but it says WSGIrequest has no attribute as data

Comment: @DhruvSinghal try `request.data` maybe because of the typo in his answer.

Comment: No @amadousow i know it should be request and i have tried that only

Comment: In middleware there request doesnt have attribute as data before getting response from view

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, i hope this will work

```
import json
import ast
def CustomMiddleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        bytes_request_data = getattr(request, '_body', request.body)
        if bytes_request_data:
            request_data = ast.literal_eval(bytes_request_data.decode('utf-8'))
            print(request_data)
```

Comment: no i have tried it and it is giving the same error

Comment: Are you using django forms to submit password from web?

Answer (score -1):

This exception is raised if you try to access the body after reading the request with HttpRequest.read() or HttpRequest.readline().

The request is probably read in a previous middleware.

From Django's documentation [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST:~:text=You%20can%20also%20read%20from%20an%20HttpRequest%20using%20a%20file%2Dlike%20interface%20with%20HttpRequest.read()%20or%20HttpRequest.readline().%20Accessing%20the%20body%20attribute%20after%20reading%20the%20request%20with%20either%20of%20these%20I/O%20stream%20methods%20will%20produce%20a%20RawPostDataException.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20read%20from%20an%20HttpRequest%20using%20a%20file%2Dlike%20interface%20with%20HttpRequest.read()%20or%20HttpRequest.readline().%20Accessing%20the%20body%20attribute%20after%20reading%20the%20request%20with%20either%20of%20these%20I/O%20stream%20methods%20will%20produce%20a%20RawPostDataException.):
You can also read from an HttpRequest using a file-like interface with HttpRequest.read() or HttpRequest.readline(). Accessing the body attribute after reading the request with either of these I/O stream methods will produce a RawPostDataException.

Comment: Could you share an example code for fixing problem ?